# The best description word for 'something you can sense'

Tags: single-word-requests

In a context, you are blindfolded, and you are trying to pick up on any of your surroundings (sound, smells, etc). In other words, you are trying to pick up on any information that you can ***sense***.

The best word I could think of was like '*sensable*' information (such word does not exist) or 'tangible' (but it is only limited to touching sense).

What would be the best description word alternative for it?

> I was killing time by picking up on any bit of >**insert word description there**< information regarding my “blindfolded” surroundings.

Comment: Note that your surroundings aren't blindfolded, you are.   And were you really killing time or were you trying to make the most of your time by trying to pick up as much about your surroundings as you could.

Comment: @Jim, In the context of the story, due to the character's personality, he really was killing time :) Note how he does not try to pick up on "as much as possible" of info, but "any" info.

Comment: Why not ***sensible*** itself?  "4. capable of being apprehended by the senses" https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/sensible

Comment: @Kris Avoid answers in comments. They cannot be community edited or peer reviewed. This discourages people from posting actual answers and defeats the core answer ranking process. A better place to post an answer is in the answer box. See: [Privileges > Comment Everywhere – Help Center](https://chat.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). See also: [Is SE enforcing “no answers in comments”? – Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10646/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Information that is able to be detected or sensed would be ***discernible*** information.  The Oxford Living Dictionaries defines it as:

> ***[discernible](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/discernible)***
> (also **discernable**)
>
> **ADJECTIVE**
>
> Able to be discerned; perceptible.
>
> *‘the scandal had no discernible effect on his career’*
> *‘the inscription was barely discernible’*

Comment: What about 'feelable'? https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/feelable I came to this word after posting, not sure which would be more appropriate to my context.

Comment: I'm not sure I've ever heard the word _feelable_ and, to be honest, would have been suspect of its validity were it not in the OED.  It certainly wouldn't read very smoothly to a native speaker, at least from the west coast of the US.  If you're not so into _discernible_, you could also use _[perceptible](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/perceptible)_ or even _[observable](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/observable)_.

Answer (score 2):

You might be looking for [sensory](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/sensory?s=t) information.

> adjective
>
> ```
> of or relating to the senses or sensation.
> ```